# Google calendar able to be read by everyone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'd like to be able to have admin users sign up in our system and have their Google calendar events be readable by everyone on the site. I'd like the customers to be able to see free slots on their schedule. Is this possible and how would I implement this in a Rails app?

Any suggestions? (I've read the OAuth and Calendar APIs, just looking for how to start setting up my app).